# Dynamic postbackurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having a problem calling a modal in asp

I need to set the postbackurl of linkbutton4 from code behind depending on what is selected in the dropdownlist! I have tried putting the postbackurl directlty on the linkbuttons tag it worked but when i change it from the code behind it doesnt BTW i change it when the link button is clicked.

Code behind for the linkbutton:

```
 protected void LinkButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          { 
              var a = (Control)sender;
              GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)a.NamingContainer;
              string b = row.Cells[0].Text;
              Session["C"] = b;
              DropDownList ddl  =(DropDownList)row.Cells[7].FindControl("DropDownList1");
              Session["D"] = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
              LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)row.Cells[7].FindControl("LinkButton4");
              if (Session["D"].ToString() == "Upload")
              {
                  lb.PostBackUrl = "preprod_design.aspx#edit";
              //    Upload();
              }
              if (Session["D"].ToString() == "Download")
              {
                  Download();
              }
             infogridbind();
          }
```

Here is the code for aspx :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ondatabound="GridView2_DataBound" 
                     onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
                     onrowcreated="GridView2_RowCreated" 
                     onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                     onrowcommand="GridView2_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                  <Columns>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="SizeSetID" SortExpression="SizeSetID"/>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Revision No." SortExpression="RevisionNo" HeaderText = "Revision No."/>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Image">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" onError = "this.style.display = 'none';" ImageUrl='<%#"~/ClientPoImage.ashx?autoId="+Eval("[SizeSetID]")%>' Width="50px" Height="40px"/>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Size Name" SortExpression="SizeName" HeaderText = "Size Name"/>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity Requested" SortExpression="QuantityRequested" HeaderText ="Quantity Requested"/>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity Received" SortExpression="QuantityReceived" HeaderText="Quantity Received"/>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Balance" SortExpression="Balance" HeaderText="Balance"/>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">      
                  <ItemTemplate >
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                          <asp:ListItem>Upload</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem>Download</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem>Edit</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem>Delete</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem>Request</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem>Receive</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton4_Click">GO</asp:LinkButton>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: have you placed the dropdown list inside gridview's template field?

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian yes.

Comment: post your code fully, i mean the grid code as well loading the values

Comment: I would suggest copying and pasting the code rather than using an image. It's sort of easier to write that way if we correct.

Comment: I've edited it already .

Comment: i think you need change postback url for link button on dropdownlist selected item changed event handler instead of on linkbutton click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `PostBackUrl` for `LinkButton` inside `DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged` event like this

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    var row = (GridViewRow)(ddl.NamingContainer);
    var lb = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("LinkButton4");

    if (ddl.SelectedValue == "Upload")
    {
        lb.PostBackUrl = "preprod_design.aspx#edit";
    }
    if (ddl.SelectedValue == "Download")
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

also you need change markup like this

```
....
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
 onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
....
```

Comment: i need the button to trigger the event .

Comment: @Vince, in event in my answer only setup postback url for link button, i don't change your code for `click` event except for movement setup postback url to selectindexchange event

Comment: @Vince possibly you need setup `PostbackUrl` to empty string if selected value not an "Upload"

Answer (score 1):

Remove `AutoPostBack="True"` From DropDownList, and in the header of page `<%@ Page Title="data"... EnableEventValidation="false" %>`
After That You just go to click event of Link button and then

```
   GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer);     

   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList1");
   If(ddl.SelectedValue =="Upload")  // or u can use ddl.SelectedItem.Text
   {
      //Upload();
   }
   else if(ddl.SelectedValue == "Download")
   {
     //Download();
   }
```

Comment: Try this <%@ Page ...  EnableEventValidation="false" %>